# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our back up questions for a total of 7 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/72ba6d67-790b-4755-9e28-5e665b6195a9/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

1. [Rory Alsop's answers](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1301/2077)
2. [Criggie's answers](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1303/2077)
3. [Rider X's answers](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1306/2077)

---

> 1. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 2. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 3. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 4. How would you deal with a moderation issue on a question where you have given an answer, or on a question that you have asked?
> 5. Do you ride, and why? If no, why not?
> 6. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 7. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 11):

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I have had to deal with this a few times - in my opinion, the most effective treatment is the standard Stack Exchange treatment: initially a warning, then a short suspension if behaviour doesn't change, followed by longer suspensions (until morale improves!) My reasoning being that although they may be a valuable contributor, their behaviour may be driving away other valuable contributors - the Code of Conduct doesn't say we should let highly valuable contributors to get away with worse behaviour than low rep...

- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Unless I feel strongly about it, I would leave it. If I did feel strongly about it, I would speak to the other mod to chat through why we had a difference of opinion. If we cannot resolve, I would either leave it, or escalate to another mod or even the CM's.

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Clean up, throw out the rubbish, respond to flags, encourage others, mediate, calm/defuse arguments - generally the janitor analogy works for most mod tasks.

- How would you deal with a moderation issue on a question where you have given an answer, or on a question that you have asked?

Hand over to another mod. It's the only sensible way to tackle these - otherwise the shout of "mod abuse" is raised:-)

- Do you ride, and why? If no, why not?

Have done for 44 years-ish. I tend to go for very light road bikes for all out speed - even for my commute (although I admit this year I have motorcycled to work far more often than I have cycled.) I have tried mountain bikes and downhill track stuff... I am probably too terrified of the lack of grip. I know that sounds daft when my old bike had a front tire only 7mm wide, but I am comfortable with tarmac.

- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I have grown very used to this over the last 7 years. It doesn't change the way I behave, but sometimes it may encourage me to take a step back if for any reason I feel myself getting annoyed at a troll, for example.

- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

For a start, I am only at 3k rep here, so that would be a long way off, but I value the ability to work on some of those areas you don't see as a non-mod such as handling flags appropriately. Currently I visit reasonably regularly and handle review tasks when I pop in

Answer (score 10):

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Why are we here?  To build a community of like-minded cyclists of all types.  Someone who contributes to the end goal of improving the overall quality and depth of the results should be valued and encouraged.

An argument that is on topic is still helping the answer to evolve and improve and should be shaped toward that goal.  An argument that becomes personal or detracts should be redirected if possible, or stopped completely.

There is no private chat/message in SE, so anything communicated has to be done so in the open.  Must be mindful of how an interaction could be interpreted, especially if the parties are of different cultures/backgrounds or even English skills.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

First, I'd sleep on it.  Sometimes speedy action can result in the wrong course of action being followed.   Then I'd think it over with specific focus on "is this enlarging the bicycles.SE resource or not?"  If no clear answer is forthcoming I'd attempt to discuss with the other mod/s in the secret moderator retreat and come to some result.

Anything more concrete would depend a lot on the question that was closed, by who and who asked it, what dupes there are, whether its a "long-term" question etc.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators moderate.  They help keep the site on-topic and on-course by limiting the most extreme swings.   Ideally the hand of direction is very lightweight, through to non-existent.  So moderators do as little as required to keep things heading in the right direction.

> How would you deal with a moderation issue on a question where you have given an answer, or on a question that you have asked?

I'd initially stand back and see how things develop.  We're all adults here and adults shouldn't need to be parented.  If my answer or question is off topic enough that it needed moderator input, I'd let the matter be handled by another mod and would simply be just a user.

Note, I asked this question originally.

> Do you ride, and why? If no, why not?

I do ride - Mostly road commuting these days with a daily round trip of ~55 km 5 days a week.   I have successfully completed some organised road racing and MTB racing events, and have worked to foster more cycling in my workplaces.  I've also done some all-day endurance rides, and attempted to travel down every road in my city (still a work in progress.)

As yet I have to try bikepacking/camping and anything to do with carbon bikes or disk brakes.

I have been an active member of ICEcycles (a community fixup cooperative) and when that got political I moved to CBC (which stands for something but we can't yet agree on.)

Why?  I ride for health and fitness, financial reasons (ie its cheaper than driving)  and I enjoy it.

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I'm indifferent.  The answers and questions should stand under their own merits, and who contributed them is immaterial in the long run.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Dunno.  I've already hit those rep levels, and have volunteered as moderator to help keep the election process moving forward.

Questions? Please ask in the comments.

Answer (score 7):

#### Rider X's Answers

> 1. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Ultimately there is an established protocol on Stack exchange, which I would follow (i.e., warnings followed by more punitive actions). That said, I feel the reason for the flags is important in how the situation should be escalated. A user that resorts to personal attacks, bullying or belittling should be have the situation escalated quicker than a user whose discourse is more course or unrefined. In the case of the latter, I would first try and work with them to improve their discourse so there may be fewer misunderstandings.

That all said, the ultimate priority is that those in the community should feel safe.  If a user makes other users feel threatened we need to take swift action regardless of their status within the community.

> 2. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I would first see if I could take some time to understand their actions before reacting.  If I strongly felt an error was made I would chat with the other moderators to see if we could come to an understanding or if they could help me better understand the situation.

> 3. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Safeguard the community and lead by example.  Also take a moment to clean up the place a bit before heading out.

> 4. How would you deal with a moderation issue on a question where you have given an answer, or on a question that you have asked?

I would recognize the conflict of interest and leave the issue to other moderators. This issue is to ripe for abuse of power, at some point you have to trust in the judgement of others.

> 5. Do you ride, and why? If no, why not?

Pretty much most days. As a recovering bike racer, it is my preferred method of transportation. Daily commute is about 45 km round trip, rain, shine and snow. Too many years racing road and mountain bikes, does however give me some useful knowledge on performance within cycling.

> 6. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

Ambivalent.  Haters will hate, lovers will love... be it as it may.

> 7. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Ability to respond quicker, and more definitively, to spam and bullying.